# Service running but threads are stopped

Tags: java, android

I have created a foreground service which spawns some repeating threads in ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.

I want to keep the service and its threads running. I only stop threads in the onDestroy method of service.

When I close the app from recents the foreground notification remains as I desire. 
But the problem is:
In Device1 threads are stopped while in Device2 they keep running.

Device1 : A miui ROM smartphone
Device2 : A google ROM smartphone

Is there any way I can keep the threads running?
I have checked that the onDestroy method is not being called.
I have enabled autostart in MIUI device.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is device issue. In the MIUI device I have tested multiple times, sometimes threads keep running while in some other case they don't.